# Binding properties of an array in an array

Tags: reactjs

This is not to start a discussion about Anugular vs REACT. I know at some point I will learn to love REACT. That is why I have started doing new apps in REACT. I just need some kind of confirmation whether I understand REACT correctly according to bindings.

I am making a function REACT component (arrow function) as I can read this is the new recommended practice. I have some data with an array of data with arrays of data. I am using all of this data to show and change content. In this specific sample I use it to toggle some menu's.

In Angular in the toggle you would have something like:

```
toggle(row){
   row.toggle=!row.toggle;
}
```

As I understand it in REACT, if you want to change content, or have some states about toggle you need hooks (correct me if I am wrong). So in REACT you would apply all of your data to a setData(someData). Something like below:

```
const toggleMenu = (section, row) => {
  console.log(section);

  setDataList(
    dataList.map(s => {
      return s.id === section.id
        ? {
            ...s,
            table: s.table.map(t => {
              return t.id === row.id
                ? { ...t, toggleDropdown: !row.toggleDropdown }
                : t;
            })
          }
        : s;
    })
  );
};
```

So I have to find my specific objects in my data, update it, and pass it all back to the hook setter. I have two concerns here. Sometimes I meet customer requirements where they want tons of data on a home page (even when it is not best practices). That will still perform with Angular. Anyone has some experience whether REACT will perform in such scenarios with this approach (so much looping)?

Last have I misunderstood something, or is this normal practice when working with REACT - or have I over complicated the task? I have made a small sample here to show a sample case:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-for-multiple-maps-gmqpp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The answer I am looking for is Yes this is the way to go, or no you have totally misunderstand the concept because .. And a plus if somebody have experince with the performance for pages with a lot of content.

Comment: Sounds like you're at a place where you need a state manager to go along with your react; [redux](https://redux.js.org/) is the most popular option.

Comment: Note that one significant difference between Angular and React is that Angular is a complete MVW framework, whereas React is simply a view library. That means that there are going to be a lot of things that Angular provides tools for out of the box that React doesn't; the expectation is that instead of trying to do everything using just react, you find tools that are built to do the specific thing you're trying and which work well with react.

Comment: Is there some kind of gudiance on when to use it? I watched a video and here it was pressented as if you want to use state between compoents (especially if you want to avoid bubbling data up through parents). And not so much within same compoenent?

Comment: Thanks. Would you say in this specific scenario redux would be the way to go?

Comment: This seems to me like a case where each of your rows should in fact be their own component, that way they can handle toggling themselves individually without any other row (or their parent) needing to care. In which case, yes; I'd say redux is likely the way to go

Comment: Thanks - appreciated. I will leave the post open for some time, hope that is OK. Would like to hear more input.